# Why is PostgreSQL stripping HTML entities in ts_headline()?

Tags: html, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm writing a prototype of a full-text search feature which will return found documents' "headlines" in the search result. Here's a slightly modified example from the [Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch-controls.html#TEXTSEARCH-HEADLINE):

```
SELECT ts_headline('english',
  'The most common type of search is to find all documents containing given query terms <b>and</b> return them in <order> of their similarity to the query.',
  to_tsquery('query & similarity'),
  'StartSel = XXX, StopSel = YYY');
```

What I would expect would be something like

```
"documents containing given XXXqueryYYY terms <b>and</b> return them in <order> of their XXXsimilarityYYY to the XXXqueryYYY."
```

What I get instead is

```
"documents containing given XXXqueryYYY terms  and  return them in   of their XXXsimilarityYYY to the XXXqueryYYY."
```

It looks like everything that looked remotely like a HTML tag is getting stripped and replaced with a single space character (note the double spaces around the `and`).

I didn't find any place in the docs that would state that Postgres is assuming the input text is HTML and the user would want the tags stripped off. The api allows overriding of `StartSel` and `StopSel` from the default `<b>` and `</b>`, so I'd think it was meant to serve a more general use-case.

Is there some setting or comment in the docs that I'm missing?

Comment: I suppose this is a security feature, to avoid strings that aren't meant to be treated as HTML from being accidentally displayed as HTML.

Comment: That's sort of sad that it's built that way, I'm fighting with it myself now. I wish there was a ts_headline with json output containing an array of arrays of the matches broken into chunks like ["left","match","right"]. I don't like how it alters the original and pulls stuff out and puts stuff into it. Maybe I'll pitch that to the developers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`<b>` and `</b>` are recognized as **tag** token. By default they are
ignored. You need to modify existing configuration or create new one:

```
=# CREATE TEXT SEARCH CONFIGURATION english_tag (COPY = english);
=# alter text search configuration english_tag
   add mapping for tag with simple;
```

Then tags aren't skipped:

```
=# select * from ts_debug('english_tag', 'query <b>test</b>');
   alias   |   description   | token |  dictionaries  |  dictionary  | lexemes
-----------+-----------------+-------+----------------+--------------+---------
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | query | {english_stem} | english_stem | {queri}
 blank     | Space symbols   |       | {}             | (null)       | (null)
 tag       | XML tag         | <b>   | {simple}       | simple       | {<b>}
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | test  | {english_stem} | english_stem | {test}
 tag       | XML tag         | </b>  | {simple}       | simple       | {</b>}
```

But even in this case ts_headline will skip tags. Because it is
[hardcoded](https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/master/src/backend/tsearch/wparser_def.c#L1923):

```
#define HLIDREPLACE(x)  ( (x)==TAG_T )
```

There is a workaround of course. It is possible to create your own text search parser extension. Example on [GitHub](https://github.com/postgrespro/pg_tsparser). And change

```
#define HLIDREPLACE(x)  ( (x)==TAG_T )
```

to

```
#define HLIDREPLACE(x)  ( false )
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `ts_headline` sanitizes HTML (strips out HTML tags) with the default `HightlightAll` option (`false`) but does *not* sanitize HTML when called with the option `HightlightAll = True`.

1. Default: option `HighlightAll = false`

```sql
SELECT ts_headline('english',
  '<div>The most common type of search is to find all documents containing given query terms <b>and</b> return them in <order> of their similarity to the query. <script type="text/javascript">document.write("something malicious");</script></div>',
  to_tsquery('query & similarity'),
  'StartSel = XXX, StopSel = YYY');
```

==>

```
documents containing given XXXqueryYYY terms  and  return them in   of their XXXsimilarityYYY to the XXXqueryYYY.  document.write("something malicious")
```

2. With option `HighlightAll = True`

```sql
SELECT ts_headline('english',
  '<div>The most common type of search is to find all documents containing given query terms <b>and</b> return them in <order> of their similarity to the query. <script type="text/javascript">document.write("something malicious");</script></div>',
  to_tsquery('query & similarity'),
  'StartSel = XXX, StopSel = YYY, HighlightAll = true');
```

==>

```
<div>The most common type of search is to find all documents containing given XXXqueryYYY terms <b>and</b> return them in <order> of their XXXsimilarityYYY to the XXXqueryYYY. <script type="text/javascript">document.write("something malicious");</script></div>
```